# What's the smallest(in size) image format which can encode xFFFFFF colors?

Tags: image, image-processing, png, jpeg, lossless

I'd like to know which is the image format which permits me to encode losslessly 0xFFFFFF colors, but I need the one which occupies less space on disk. I know that BMP, JPEG(variant), TIFF, PNG,(just to say some) are lossless, but which one is the one that, considering also zipping or whatever, can occupy less space?

Comment: Zipping will usually make an encoded image larger, not smaller, because there is almost maximum entropy (no patterns), yet Zip adds header information. Zip is also usually not better than a compressed image format, as the image formats can make assumptions about typical bit patterns that Zip cannot. As for which gives the smallest file size, just try them out with images typical for your domain.

Comment: Apples and oranges. Are you looking for the image format with the *smallest overhead*, when saving a 1x1 px image? Also note your limit of "0xFFFFFF colors" seems rather arbitrary. True-color images can save one color more than that.

Comment: ... By the way, PNG wins hands down with a lossless compression of [841 : 1](http://www.mywebsite.force9.co.uk/png/png24.htm). No zipping (or whatever) can beat that.

Comment: I said 0xFFFFFF because I only care about all possible RGB, but I think that PNG is the best way to go, as you suggested, and thanks for the page.

Comment: @Christian 24-bit RGB actually encodes 0x1000000 colors, numbered 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFF. And yes, PNG is awesome at compression. There are even tools to optimize PNGs to get them even smaller by removing unnecessary information, but sometimes that's overkill.

Answer (score 7):

A PNG image (16million.png) containing all possible RGB888 colors was published in 1996.  It occupies 115,989 bytes.  I have converted the same image to a MNG file of just 472 bytes.  The current version of pngcrush (1.8.0) brings the PNG file down to 91514 bytes.
See Khalid Sayood's [Lossless Compression Handbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=LjQiGwyabVwC&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388#v=onepage&q&f=false).

If on the other hand you are asking about a format that can represent a single pixel in any one of the 16 million colors, then PNG takes 69 bytes
including the 8-byte PNG signature, the IHDR, IEND, and IDAT chunk overhead, and several bytes of zlib overhead within the IDAT chunk, while a simple PPM file only takes 14 bytes to represent such single-pixel images (P6 1 1 255 \n red green blue).

Between those extremes, the best compression depends upon the content of the image.